# Understanding foundational terms: notions, objects and meta-objects

Tags: proof-writing, self-learning, problem-solving, foundations

I am trying to take my problem solving skill to next level. It looks like It takes a lot of mathematical discipline. Here, [This post](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-sources-for-ad-hoc-competitive-programming-problems-to-practice-getting-better-at-ad-hoc-solving) buys me to get better at proof writing.

So, I think is useful to get started with foundation of mathematics. [This site](http://settheory.net) looks good as start.

Now, I am stuck understanding three basic definition.

**Notion**: Each theory has its own list of notions, usually designated by common names, that are the kinds of variables used by the theory. **Is notion are synonyms to class in OOP?**

**And what are the one-model theory and meta-objects?**

---

**Is there a text that intuitively teach these topics?**

Comment: I don't understand what this means: "Is notion are synonyms to class in OOP?" There are also a few other things here that aren't clear. I think this is partly because I don't know the terms you're using, and partly because it is hard to understand your English. You could consider writing the post in your own language as well as English, and someone who can read your language may be able to clarify what you mean.

Comment: @David, By OOP I meant "object oriented programming". And, "problem solving" refers to the solution of mathematical and computational problems.

Comment: I still don't understand "Is notion are synonyms to class in OOP?" (To be honest, it is difficult for me to understand the structure of the sentence.) What does "buys me" mean?

Comment: Do you mean: "Is the concept of 'notion' described on the website synonymous with the concept of 'class' in object-oriented programming?"